# Is A* algorithm suitable in starting and ending positions composed of multiple neighbouring cells

Tags: path-finding

Can the A* algorithm be efficiently applied to a NxM rectangular grid with varying travel cost involved while moving to any cell and starting location is not a single cell but is composed of multiple closed cells; say a cluster of neighbouring cells where a neighbour of a cell is any of the eight cells surrounding it? (The ending cell is similar to that.)
If so, then can anyone please show the way and if not what can be a good procedure to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the A* algorithm be efficiently applied to a NxM rectangular grid with varying travel cost [...]

Yes, A* works on Graphs of any type as long as edge costs are positive. Instead of phrasing the graph as a grid with regular neighbours, construct it so that grid cells which are connected have edges between them.

Edge costs can also be arbitrary as long as they are non-negative (positive or zero).

Make sure that your heuristic remains admissible.

> and starting location is not a single cell but is composed of multiple closed cells;

Yes, this should be possible.

- Decide on an initial cost for each of the cells. Zero as costs for all of them would be easiest.
- Instead of adding just the single start vertex into the priority queue, add all the multiple cells into the priority queue.

> say a cluster of neighbouring cells where a neighbour of a cell is any of the eight cells surrounding it? (The ending cell is similar to that.)

The goal can also be composed of multiple cells.

- Just make it such that reaching any of the goal cells terminates the search.
- Make sure you to compute the heuristic as the minimum of the individual heuristics to each goal cell. (I.e. compute heuristic for each goal cell, then take minimal value.)